# Cannot resolve method 'loadAnimation' in 'AnimationUtils'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, error-handling

```
    fabOpen= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_bottom_anim);
    fabClose= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_bottom_anim);
    rotateForward= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_open_anim);
    rotateBackward= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_close_anim);
```

in the above code,loadAnimation is showing red(error), and an error appears "Cannot resolve method 'loadAnimation' in 'AnimationUtils'".

I was trying to add animation on a floatbutton. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is two types of AnimationUtils..

1. AnimationUtils (android.view.animation)
2. AnimationUtils (com.google.android.material.animation)

choose carefully what u have required.
if u select 1) that loadAnimation() is working otherwise it will show you red(error) in code.